# Auto-filling a table column with another tables' column?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Having a table listing definitions identified by an ID column, I would like to create a new table with the same ID column without copying/pasting it... Is there any way to autofill or reference a table column in another one with Excel 2010 ?

Basically, I have a table A:

```
ID    | Definition
------.------------
FOO-1 | Text
FOO-2 | Text
BAR-1 | Text
BAR-2 | Text
```

How can you generate a table B referencing the same table A's ID columns - without copying the entire column in A :

```
Table A ID column | Whatever
------------------.------------
Table A ID column | Text
Table A ID column | Text
Table A ID column | Text
Table A ID column | Text
...
```

As a database, table B ID column would be a foreign key from A...

Thx !

Comment: Can you try to be more specific please?  I'm thinking `INDIRECT` could play a role in your solution, but I'm puzzled about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Marc I illustrated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to create a new table with the same ID column without copying/pasting it.

Let's suppose the following:

1. Table A is on Sheet1, under columns A and B,
2. Table A has 2000 rows,
3. You want the IDs under Table A's column A to be in a Table B's column A,
4. Tables B is on Sheet2, under columns A and B.
5. Table A's ID in cell A2000 = `BAR-2`

Do the following:

Go to the Sheet2, and type on cell A2000:

```
=BAR-2
```

Still on Sheet2, give a click with the left mouse button on cell A1.Then, press: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>shift</kbd> + `down_arrow` to select Cells A1 to A2000.

Click on "Home" -> "Find & Select" --> "Replace"

Leave the field "Find what" blank and type on field "Replace with":

```
=Sheet1!A1:A2000
```

[image]

Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>. Done!!